# Regex for "111 -> c:\my source\file1.cpp (no code)" (C#)

Tags: c#, regex

I need to parse a string with the following contents in C#:

```
111 -> c:\my source\file1.cpp (no code)
112 -> c:\my source\file1.cpp
113 -> c:\my source\file2.cpp
114 -> c:\my source\file3.cpp
115 -> c:\my source\file2.cpp (no code)
```

I need to get the first number and the files names, but only for records with code (so there should not be (no code) at the end.
Currently I have ended up with this rexex

```
new Regex(@"^(\d+) -> ([^\r\n]*)", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

It is really simple, but it gives me lines, that I don't want to see.
All my tries to write something like `^(\d+) -> ([^\r\n]*)(?! \(no code\))` failed.
Actually, this may be a more generic example. Like:
How to match **BBB** in a string of form **"aaa BBB ccc"**, where BBB can be any set of charaters, and aaa and ccc are known tokens, that consist of the same set of character as in BBB?

Comment: What do you mean by "no code?"

Comment: @Cybernate: Why did you edit out the "no code" strings in the question.... I think these were key to understanding the question. Also, I don't think it's fair to edit the example regex, as that's what he's asking for help on.

Comment: @BG100: Added it back.. I think I lost them while formatting the question.

Comment: (no code) is just a literal string. That can be in the end of file name separated with space.

Comment: With some help in comments, I got this regex as a result: `^(\d+) -> (.+?)(?<! \(no code\))(\r|\z)` It matches line without (no code) and also, doesn`t include \r in resulting group. \z is needed for the case of last line, without \r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why can't you just use:

```
^(\d+) -> ([\w:\\\s.]+)$
```

Apply multi-line and it won't allow `(no code)` as it's not contained in the last group (no parenthesis allowed in last group's class)

**[demo](http://regexr.com?2tm6b)**

If you do need to permit parenthesis in the file name, you can use something like:

```
^(\d+) -> (.+?)(?<! \(no code\))$
```

Which uses a negative look-behind instead (so you can make sure it doesn't come before the end of line).

**[demo](http://regexr.com?2tm6e)**

Comment: It seems, that your demos use a bit different regex engine, than in .Net, because, demos work, and in .Net it still capture every line, including (no code)

Comment: @Vladimir, you must be talking about the second regex.  RegExr is powered by ActionScript 3, and in AS3, `$` matches before the `\r` in `\r\n` (carriage-return + linefeed), but in .NET it matches *between* the `\r` and `\n`.  In [this online demo](http://ideone.com/6AH2p), the regex works as-is, but locally I had to alter it like this: `^(\d+) -> (.+?)(?<! \(no code\)\r?)$`.

Comment: ...that problem aside (and I consider it a bug in the .NET regex flavor), the lookbehind approach is more correct than the lookahead version in your question.  But Brad's first regex works fine for me; is there some reason you can't use that?

Comment: @Brads, first example doesn`t match anything in my example app. PS I use Expresso for tests.

Comment: I marked this as answer, since it is the closes to correct. And you only have to replace $ with (\r|\z) to overcome .net implementation specifics.

Comment: @VladimirPerevalov: The regex, as written, works [fine for me](http://www.ideone.com/PfVzm), just make sure you set your regex options to `Multiline`.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with c# and it its working for me.

```
new Regex(@"^(\d+)\s->\s(.+\.\w+)(?!.*\(no code\))$", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

It's not that different from your try,

```
^(\d+) -> ([^\r\n]*)(?! \(no code\))
```

but I think your middle part `([^\r\n]*)` matches to much, so that the negative lookahead will not match anymore.

Update:

I tested @Brad Christie 's solution

```
new Regex(@"^(\d+) -> (.+?)(?<! \(no code\))$", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

and it is also working with .net/c# in my environment, so +1

Comment: The first one doesn`t match anything at all. And second one, again matches all strings. Actually, this one `^(\d+) -> (.+?)(?<! \(no code\)\r?)$` by @AlanMoore works correctly.

Comment: Fine, then you found your problem, I tested only with \n as newline.